# Python bindings for libtorrent-rasterbar are not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, libtorrent

I'm running Debian 6.0.6

I've downloaded  latest version of libtorrent-rasterbar from here: http://code.google.com/p/libtorrent/downloads/detail?name=libtorrent-rasterbar-0.16.6.tar.gz&can=2 and installed it:

```
./configure --enable-python-binding
make
make install
cd bindings/python
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

now I want to test whether the library works:

```
>>> import libtorrent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The packaged version of libtorrent from the distributive's repository had some funny behaviour (complaining on boost dependences), so I've decided to upgrade. The same situation is on both of my debian boxes, yet ubuntu box is fine.

old error message from my debian box:

```
  File "ar.py", line 15, in create
    s.start_dht()
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    session.start_dht(session)
did not match C++ signature:
    start_dht(libtorrent::session {lvalue}, libtorrent::entry)
```

Comment: did libtorrent build successfully? It looks like libtorrent-rasterbar may not have installed correctly (which the python module depends on)

Comment: @Arvid make and make install went fine and without error and locate locates many instances of libtorrent, for example /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/libtorrent.so
How do I point python to the actual binary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for the shared object file and add it to your path.

```
sudo updatedb
locate libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7
```

This should output `/<path_to_directory>/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.7`

Add this to your `~/.profile` or temporarily tell Python where to look:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/<path_to_directory>/
```

See more detailed installation instructions [here](https://coderwall.com/p/muvnow).